# Why the gradient of a ReLU for X>0 is 1?

Tags: deep-learning, gradient-descent, activation-function

- Gradient is derivative of several variables.
- I can't understand why is the gradient of a ReLU for X>0 is 1 ? and 0 for x < 0 ?

I tried to search for proof and examples but didn't found any good examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReLU function is defined as follows: $f(x) = max(0, x)$, meaning that the output of the function is maximum between the input value and zero. This can also be written as follows:

$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x \leq 0, \\
x  & \text{if } x \gt 0
\end{cases}
$

If we then simply take the derivate of the two outputs with respect to $x$ we get the gradient for input values below zero and value greater than or equal to zero.

$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x \leq 0, \\
1  & \text{if } x \gt 0
\end{cases}
$

Therefore the gradient of the ReLU function is zero for values up to and including zero and 1 for positive values.

Comment: The derivative _is not defined_ at zero.  You can take the derivative piecewise inside intervals, but not at their endpoints; and a quick look at the graph of ReLU makes it clear that the derivative doesn't exist at 0.  (For the purposes of back-propagation, a "sub-gradient" is sufficient, and zero works for that purpose.)